# How do I search nested elements with a query string in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've read the Query String documentation but did not find any references to nested fields: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

I could use the JSON formatted nested query/filter but would really like to use query strings as they are more convenient for ad-hoc searching. The fields I'm interested in are declared as 'nested' in the mapping e.g.

```
"tags": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        // more fields, snipped
    }
},
```

A query string like `q=tags.name:MyTag` never returns any results. The same query expressed using a nested term query or filter works.

Thanks!
- Sharat

Comment: You could use nested query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-nested-query.html and inside it use Query string query. From what I know there's no way to access nested fields without telling elastic that it needs to load nested documents. That's because nested documents are separate documents in index, which are stored nearby for quick access. They are not loaded eagerly by default for optimization.

Comment: It is not supported at the moment. Here is the [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322) where the discussion took place. Someone created a [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11339) for the new feature, but it's still open as it conflicts with existing code.